# passing parameters with special characters from code

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

I am writing an application page that passes parameters to a ready made SharePoint PowerShell scripts that accepts parameters. However, I am having exceptions with my parameters that have spaces and special characters.

I pass parameters like this:

```cs
powerShell.AddParameter("param", passedparameter);
powershell.invoke();
```

In my script, this is how the structure is:

```psh
Param($param1, $param, $param2)
```

The parameter that have special characters are null every time I run and debug it. But when I run it using the management shell it runs successfully. I have tried enclosing it with quotes, parentheses. I have also tried URL encoding but nothing was successful.

```cs
byte[] byteselectedParam = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameter);
string convertedParam = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteselectedParam );
```

Comment: Can you show the original assignment of `passedparameter`? Where does the value come from? What special characters does it contain?

Comment: hi @MathiasR.Jessen, it just comes from a drop down box the special characters are accented letters and spaces.

Comment: Could you maybe insert a breakpoint right before `AddParameter()` and verify that `passedparameter` actually contains the value from the dropdown box?